# python #The description in the internet window called "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server." can not be processed any more

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

```
import os
import time
import  random
import  webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
binary = 'C:/Users/lee/Documents/IEDriverServer.exe'
browser = webdriver. Ie (binary)
browser.set_window_size(533,533)
browser.get('https://www.naver.com/')
time.sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: #The description in the internet window called "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server." can not be processed any more.

This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.

And it is no longer connected to the naver homepage. (There are computers that can and do not have computers.)

I installed the latest version of the IEDriverServer.exe driver and thought I got the protected mode, but when I took the log, I found browser = webdriver. Ie (binary) stops at this part.#

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points :

1. Keep the required `imports` only. Remove the unwanted `imports` to keep things simpler.
2. Need to be careful with extra spaces as **`Python`** is sensitive to **`spaces`** and **`indents`**.
3. To mention `OS` paths either use escaped back slashes `(\\)` or use single front slashes `(/)` along with the raw `(r)` switch.
4. Here is your own working code with some minor tweaks:

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
   import time

   cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
   cap['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
   browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe")
   browser.get('https://www.naver.com/')
   browser.set_window_size(533,533)
   time.sleep(10)
   browser.quit()
   ```

### Update

As you are seeing the error as **`WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode set`**, follow the steps below and execute your tests :

- On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
- Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.
- The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
- For Windows 10, you also need to set "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100% in display settings.

Comment: An error occurs.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 8, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\Users\\PPCCCP\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer.exe")
  File "C:\Users\PPCCCP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py",
 line 82, in __init__ raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
enium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode set